# Definite integral with dx on top

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{3}\frac{dx}{x-1}$$

I was looking at this problem, and have not seen dx ever go on top, how might I approach this problem?

Comment: it just means $\int_0^3\frac{1}{x-1}dx$

Comment: ohh, here I was tearing myself thinking it was a trick, thanks!

Comment: @mushi Just sloppy notation to save some space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as 
$$3\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$$
$$\int_0^3 \frac{1}{x-1}\,dx=\int_0^3 \frac{dx}{x-1}$$
I will also note that this integral doesn't even converge in the usual sense, unless you look at its Cauchy Principal Value.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that it's not exactly "just" like the case of multiplying numbers, since the $dx$ really isn't being multiplied. But the $\textit{analogy}$ with multiplication is certainly the motivation behind writing the integrand this way.

Comment: Yes, this is true.